# bag file to pcd files

Tags: ros, pcl, bag-to-pcd, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i try to convert bag file using the following command to pcd file then i get multiple pcd files. is this correct ? How can i obtain single pcd file from a bag file.

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd <input_file.bag> <topic> <output_directory>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235063/bag-file-to-pcd-files/) by [noman](https://answers.ros.org/users/26704/noman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vignesh_93](https://answers.ros.org/users/65377/vignesh_93/) on 2021-02-08**:
can this node be used to convert to point cloud data directly from the "scan" topic which is in laser reading format or does the topic need to be a point cloud data publishing topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bag_to_pcd file will use the topic that you choose as input, and turn each sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 message on that topic into it's own PCD file.

If you want a single PCD file, you need to use a tool like the point_cloud_assembler (http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) to concatenate all of the clouds together into a single cloud.  You can then use the bag_to_pcd tool to save that new single cloud.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2016-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1